# write.table() results in permission denied - common solutions don't work

Tags: r, permission-denied, administrator, working-directory, write.table

Can't seem to get permission to write files in R.

Using Windows 10. Only one user account in my computer, have tried running RStudio and Rgui as administrator. `getwd()` confirms `'C:/Users/name/R'` is my working directory. I've gone to properties of the folder and SYSTEM and user have all permissions to write. Have tried changing the directory to no avail.

Using 
    `write.table(dataframe, "C:/Users/name/R", sep = "|")` and I get the following error:

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :    cannot open the
>   connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, ifelse(append,
>   "a", "w")) :   cannot open file 'C:/Users/name/R': Permission denied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path you give to `write.table` should name a file.  You have it naming a directory. R won't replace that directory with a file (thank goodness).

Try this:

```
write.table(dataframe, "C:/Users/name/R/dataframe.txt", sep = "|")
```

Comment: Such a simple and ridiculous fix. Thanks!